# Conversion of Inteface from vb.net to c#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, interface

I have a control that overrides the protected GetService method and assigns it to the IServiceProvider interface:

```
Class MyControl
    Inherits Control
    Implements IServiceProvider

    Protected Overrides Sub GetService(t as Type) as Object Implements IServiceProvider.GetService
    End Sub

End Class
```

I'm struggling to convert this to c#. I've tried implicit v. explicit but I must be getting the syntax wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original VB.NET method is protected, so I guess it's the equivalent of explicit interface implementation in C#:

```
class MyControl : Control, IServiceProvider
{
     object IServiceProvider.GetService(Type t)
     {
         ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Not equivalent to explicit implementation because you can call it from a reference to `MyControl` in VB.Net.  The translation between the two can really only be expresed with a combination of implicit and explicit implementation.

Comment: Thats the one cheers. I tried everything but leaving off the name of the method.

Comment: @Jules: Just realize that this probably will not behave the way you want it to behave.  See JaredPar or my answer for details...

Answer (score 7):

You would do this like:

```
class MyControl : Control, IServiceProvider
{
     // Explicitly implement this
     object IServiceProvider.GetService(Type t)
     {
          // Call through to the protected version
          return this.GetService(t);
     }

     // Override the protected version...
     protected override object GetService(Type t)
     {
     }
}
```

That being said, Control already implements IServiceProvider (via Component).  You really can just do:

```
class MyControl : Control
{
     protected override object GetService(Type t)
     {
     }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It says that method cannot implement it because it's not public.

Comment: @Jules: Sorry about that - was too fast, and forgot about one of the intereting quirks in VB.NET - I updated, including showing that it's really not necessary in the first place...

Comment: @Reed, you still cannot use `protected` in your example, because the interface method must be public. Nor can you use `override`, as you'll get an "no suitable method found to override" compiler error (unless the `GetService` implementation was also marked virtual, applies to the MyControl : Control case).

Comment: @Anthony: Not true.  I'm overriding Component.GetService here, which is protected virtual.  After my initial snafu, I put this in a compiler to make sure it works (and it does).  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.getservice.aspx

Comment: @Reed, well, that will teach me to consider the actual objects being referenced instead of generalities. Oops. But yes, if `Control` (or it's bases) implements the interface explicity and provides a virtual method with a similar name, the code indeed works.

Comment: @Anthony: Yeah, Windows.Forms.Control is implemented oddly, to say the least ;)

Comment: @Reed, though you would expect it, Component does not implement IServiceProvider. It does, however, have the GetService method.

Answer (score 4):

There is a bit of a corner issue with VB.Net interface implementation that needs to be considered when porting to C#.  A implemented interface method in VB.Net essentially uses both implicit and explicit interface implementations in the same line.  This allows for cases like mismatched names and non-public implementations.

For example the following is also a legal implementation of `IServiceProvider`

```
Class Example 
  Implements IServiceProvider

  Private Sub GetServiceWrongName(t As Type) As Object Implements IServiceProvider.GetService
    ...
  End Sub
End Class
```

It translates to roughly the following C# code

```
class Example : IServiceProvider {
  public object GetServiceWrongName(t as Type) {
    ..
  }

  object IServiceProvider.GetService(t as Type) {
    return GetServiceWrongName(t);
  }

}
```

Comment: Does it implement it this way, or implement the interface explicitly?  I thought it was the latter...

Comment: @Reed, the code it actually produces is just not representable in C# at all.  It generates a single method which has the IL op codes that specify it as the override to `IServiceProvider.GetService`.  I find it's instructive to take my example, compile it and view the IL dump in reflector.  The only way to get equivalent code in C# (non-public, different names, etc ...) is the two method approach.